# How to Translate Template Strings in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, internationalization, multilingual, drupal-themes

I have some strings in my theme/template and I was hoping to translate them with t(), but they don't appear in /admin/build/translate/search. I could do it in PHP code and make my own function, but is this "the right way"?

Comment: did you view page with t() of these strings in browser?

Comment: Like Nikit suggested, you first have to view the page at least once. That way the template file gets processed and drupal recognizes translateable strings. These should then appear in the locale_source table and you should be able to translate them via translate interface.

Answer (score 0):

Like Nikit and Paul pointed out, opening the page in order for the strings to be processed and added to the translation table is an option, but if you have many theme files there is a module that precisely scans a folder for translatable strings and builds a POT file so you can translate all those strings easier and faster. I'd highly recommend you http://drupal.org/project/potx and http://www.poedit.net/